# Provisioning profile doesn't include entitlement

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, nfc, apple-developer-account

:)

I use eas (ExpoApplicationService) to build my react native NFC iOS app, and when I use

> com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers

and

> com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers

I always get this error from fastlane:

> ❌  error: Provisioning profile "*[expo] com.freeridre.senityApp
> AppStore 2021-07-23T21:58:47.340Z" doesn't include the
> com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes and
> com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers
> entitlements. (in target 'senity' from project 'senity')

My entitlements look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
    <array>
      <string>12FC</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
      <string>NDEF</string>
      <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
      <string>A0000001020304</string>
      <string>A000000063504B43532D3135</string>
      <string>E828BD080F</string>
      <string>D2760000850100</string>
      <string>D2760000850101</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

My info.plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>senity</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>com.freeridre.senityApp</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>exp+senityiosnfc</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Senity Security Systems Ltd.</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
    <array>
      <string>12FC</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
      <string>NDEF</string>
      <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
      <string>A0000001020304</string>
      <string>A000000063504B43532D3135</string>
      <string>E828BD080F</string>
      <string>D2760000850100</string>
      <string>D2760000850101</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @daniel-pal, I think you might need to [add the `selectIdentifiers`
 prop to your `app.json`](https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager#props) to specify the acceptable application IDs.

Comment: Yes, I tried, and after that I got the error that I mentioned.